# Haskell types error: Inferred type is less polymorphic than expected

Tags: haskell

I'm messing around with Haskell at the moment and for the life of me I cannot figure out why the following works.....

```
square :: (Num a) => a -> a 
square x = x * x 
dx = 0.0000001
deriv1 :: (Fractional a) => (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
deriv1 g = (\x -> ((g (x + 2) - (g x)) / 0.0000001 ))   
main = printf "res==%g %g\n" (square 5.12::Double) ((deriv1 square) 2::Float)
```

but this doesn't....

```
square :: (Num a) => a -> a 
square x = x * x 
dx = 0.0000001
deriv1 :: (Fractional a) => (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
deriv1 g = (\x -> ((g (x + 2) - (g x)) / dx ))          
main = printf "res==%g %g\n" (square 5.12::Double) ((deriv1 square) 2::Float)
```

note I've used `dx` in the derv1 function this time. I'm new to Haskell so any in depth discussion on types will likely whoosh past me so fast I'll die spinning. It's imperative I have something resembling an imperative answer or it will almost certainly be lost on me this early in my Haskell career.

The error message I'm getting is:

```
Inferred type is less polymorphic than expected
  Quantified type variable `a' is mentioned in the environment:
    dx :: a (bound at sicp-1.40.hs:12:0)
When trying to generalise the type inferred for `deriv1'
  Signature type:     forall a. (Fractional a) => (a -> a) -> a -> a
  Type to generalise: (a -> a) -> a -> a
In the type signature for `deriv1'
When generalising the type(s) for `deriv1'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the error because of the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction). Since you don't give a type signature to `dx` it ends up inferred as `Double` in this case. You can either give an explicit, polymorphic signature like

```
dx :: Fractional a => a
dx = 0.0000001
```

or you can disable the monomorphism restriction by including this line at the top of your source file

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

Answer (score 4):

The probably best way to avoid ending up in the monomorphism restriction is to make `dx` local:

```
deriv1 :: (Fractional a) => (a->a) -> a->a
deriv1 g = (\x -> ((g (x + dx) - (g x)) / dx ))
   where dx = 0.0000001
```

Note that I changed `2` for `dx` as well, that was kind of wrong in your definition. (Not programming-wise, but mathematically.)

BTW, you can also write this simply

```
deriv1 g x = (g (x + dx) - g x) / dx
```

Haskell translates it to a lambda automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the monomorphism restriction, the type of `dx` is defaulted to Double. So when you divide by `dx` in `deriv1`, Haskell infers that the other operand to `/` and the result must also have type Double. But since your type signature says `a`, you get the error you do.

You can fix this by either explicitly declaring `dx` to have the type `Fractional a => a` or by disabling the monomorphism restriction.